# How to send array as argument?

Tags: python

I want to use subprocess to open an application. However the amount of argument is not fixed. What's the best way to approach this?

```
subprocess.call( "path/to/app", arg[0], arg[1], arg... )
```

minimum arg[] is 1 but it can get as large and 10 or 20. What's the best way to send them to aubprocess's argument in this case?

Comment: @zenpoy: unfortunately that is not relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to do

```
subprocess.call(["path/to/app"] + arg)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only one argument, and it's a list:

```
>>> subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
0
```

Taken directly from the examples at http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

You should be doing `subprocess.call(["path/to/app", arg[0], arg[1], arg... ])`, for example:

```
subprocess.call(["path/to/app"]+arg)
```